# Fork tube seals Suzuki sv650

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, suzuki, forks, sv650

So I recently inherited a 2002 Suzuki sv650... It was garage kept for about 6 years and needs some love.

I noticed that the rubber seals on top of the fork shock tubes won't stay with the tubes... Aka they slide up and stay there...

Should these be replaced or can they be fixed with some gasket sealant?

Anyone think the tubes should be replaced?

Comment: Sounds like a question for @DukatiKiller to me '-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rubber seals that are staying on the inner fork tube after riding are called dust seals.  They are one of two seals that are used to seal the fork slider onto the inner fork tube.

The first seal you see, the dust seal, does not prevent the oil from leaking out.  When you look into the the area where the dust seal would go you will see your oil seal.

I recommend you change your dust seals if they are not staying seated into the slider.

IF you are leaking ANY oil whatsoever from your forks you will need to change your oil seals.

The seal cost is very low but of course there is a labor component.  I believe for those types of forks you are looking at about 4 hours of labor if you have a shop perform the task.

Comment: As I suspected. This would be something I'd do myself but I was hoping to avoid it.